# How to measure memory bandwidth usage

Tags: memory, bandwidth, profiling

I am trying to determine how close to being bandwidth-limited a code I have written is, so I was wondering whether there are any tools out there to determine memory bandwidth usage? The code I have is a command-line *nix code, and if possible I'd like to measure the bandwidth usage on Mac (but Linux is ok too).

Comment: in the equivalent of task manager (task monitor?) there isn't some that will tell you how much bandwidth a process has consumed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html). Memory bandwidth is essentially the same as misses in the lowest-level cache.